# Getting Address from Google's Reverse Geocoding

Tags: javascript, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I'm trying to have the coordinates change automatically based on the person's location. Consequently, I have DarkSky's API for the longitude and latitude and am trying to use those coordinates in Google's reverse Geocoding code to have it return an address that the user can see. At the moment, the user can only see the coordinates. I have been able to successfully query the country, but am unable to get the address. For this reason, I am taking a different approach, so that I can get the country and address that the user is located in. How can I use Google's reverse geocoding to spit out an address?I have provided a link to my codepen(which has the plug-ins)

https://codepen.io/baquino1994/pen/ayJOod?editors=1010

HTML

```
<head>
  <meta charset ="utf-8" />
  <meta name = "viewport" content ="width=device-width, intitial-scale = 1"/>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href ="style.css"/>
  <link rel = "http://ipinfo.io"/>
  <title>Weather</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src = https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js></script>
</head>



<body>
 <header>
   <h1><div id="minutely"></div></h1>
 <h2><div id="location"></div></h2>
 </header>
  <p><span id="city"</span></p>


  <p> <span id="country"></span></p>
  <div id="temp" id="tempunit"></div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="BT1">Change Metric</button>

</body>
```

JS

```
function weather(){
    function success(position){
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude= position.coords.longitude;
        // location.innerHTML = "Latitude:" + latitude+"°"+ "Longitude: " + longitude+'°';
        var theUrl = url +apiKey + "/"+ latitude+","+ longitude +"?callback=?";

    $.getJSON(theUrl, function(data){
        $("#temp").html(data.currently.temperature)
 $("#minutely").html(data.minutely.summary)


  $.ajax({
      url:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=AIzaSyBpiTf5uzEtJsKXReoOKXYw4RO0ayT2Opc', dataType: 'json',
     success: function(results){
         $("#city").text(results.results[3].address_components[4].long_name)   
  $("#country").text(results.results[0].address_components[3].types)

     }


 }




    )}
             );


  function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: 40.731, lng: -73.997}
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow);
  });
}

function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
  var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
  geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
      if (results[0]) {
        map.setZoom(11);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng,
          map: map
        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        window.alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}




  } 


var location = document.getElementById("location");
var apiKey = "3827754c14ed9dd9c84afdc4fc05a1b3";
var url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/";
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
// location.innerHTML = "Locating...";

   }
$(document).ready(function(){ 
weather();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow !
First rule of thumb never post code which contains critical information of your project, such as `apiKey` mentioned above.
From what i understood it seems you want to extract country and city from the response (json object) returned by reverse geocoding,given below is the structure of address_components array contained within result object
[image]

To extract required information i suggest you to iterate on address_components array and check `types[0]` . From [google docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

1. **country** indicates the national political entity, and is typically
   the highest order type returned by the Geocoder.
2. **administrative_area_level_1** indicates a first-order civil entity
   below the country level. Usually this is **state**
3. **locality** indicates an incorporated city or town political entity.

In your code i see :

```
$("#city").text(results.results[3].address_components[4].long_name)   
$("#country").text(results.results[0].address_components[3].types)
```

Replace this with city and country as explained above , i think you are good to go :)

Hope this helps !